# Uploading file using AJAX request

Tags: ajax, django, file

I'm trying to upload a file using AJAX. I tried to do it using formData() object as well. How can I add a file to following Ajax request?

```js
  $.ajax({ 
        url: '/api/add_new_pair/', 
        method: "POST", 
        type: 'POST', 
        FILES: { 
            'image' : file,
        },
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
            'text': text,
        },
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
```

Comment: Post your code using formData(), and what error did you receive?

Answer (score 0):

> You can access the multipart(multimedia) data(header along with data in base64 format) in request.FILES and other data in request.POST

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{csrf_token}}');
data.append('image', $('#image-id').files[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save_design/",
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,

    beforeSend: function() {
    },

    success: function(t) {
    },

    complete: function() {
    },

    error: function(t) {}
    }), 
}
```